# How can I play a stream file m3u on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, m3u

I want to integrate a webplayer on my website to play my m3u streaming file.

I found this javascript file on github and tried to get it running. Unfortunately without success.

https://github.com/aitorciki/jquery-playlist

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.playlist.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('audio').playlistParser({
        proxy: 'proxy.php'
        });
    });
</script>

<audio controls src="http://www.stream.com/stream.m3u">
</body>
</html>
```

the proxy.php file:

```
$url = file_get_contents($_GET["url"]);
echo $url;
```

Or is there a completely different solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems the playlist plugin works with jQuery v3, not jQuery v1. After I modify your code to use jQuery v3, it works for me

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.playlist.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('audio').playlistParser({
        proxy: 'proxy.php'
        });
    });
</script>

<audio controls src="http://www.stream.com/stream.m3u">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I changed the code but it still doesn't work.
Could it be that the files are on a different web server than the m3u file? What about the Error Message if you run the snippet:
  "message": "TypeError: $(...).playlistParser is not a function",